Remove Duplicate Entra ID Accounts on Windows 11
On a lot of our company PCs, we have two identical Entra ID accounts which are causing a conflict and giving users lots of error messages related to "Verifying their account" or "Work or School Account Sign-In".
Does anyone know how to remove just one of these without removing the other? Of course, doing it through the actual settings page would remove the Windows profile and require local sign-in. I'm looking for a more creative way like Powershell or Registry. Thanks!
Apologies for having to black out the emails for privacy concerns, you can trust me when I say they are all the same email address.

